# Cisco ASA 5505 config for VPN traversal

Tags: vpn, cisco

I've recently installed an ASA 5505 to connect several sites via site-to-site VPN which is working just fine.  I also required remote access VPN for users which has also been configured using L2TP/IPSec.  However, I'm having trouble with the configuration to allow the remote access users to access systems on any of the site-VPN connected networks.  Here's the general layout in a hub/spoke configuration:

10.100.20.0/24 - central office (hub)
10.100.50.0/24 - remote office 1
10.100.60.0/24 - remote office 2
10.100.70.0/24 - remote office 3

10.200.0.0/24 - remote access pool

The central office can communicate with any remote office and all remote offices can communicate with the central office.  The remote access users can communicate only with the central office which is their VPN (L2TP) endpoint.

I'm curious what NAT and/or routing configuration do I need to consider to allow the remote access user to access any of the connected remote offices?

Many thanks in advance!
Chris

HERE IS THE CONFIG (with necessary obfuscation):

```
ASA Version 8.2(1) 
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password ***** encrypted
passwd ***** encrypted
names
name 208.67.222.222 opendns1
name 208.67.220.220 opendns2
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.100.20.254 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 200.200.200.2 255.255.255.252 
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns domain-lookup inside
dns domain-lookup outside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server opendns2
 name-server opendns1
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network opendns-servers
 network-object host opendns2
 network-object host opendns1
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.50.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_2_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.60.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_3_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.70.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.50.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.60.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.70.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 10.200.0.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any object-group opendns-servers eq domain 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP host 10.100.20.1 any eq domain 
access-list inside_access_in extended deny object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip any any 
access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.200.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm-buffer-size 300
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
ip local pool RA-pool 10.200.0.1-10.200.0.50 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool test-pool 10.100.20.200-10.100.20.209 mask 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any inside
icmp deny any echo outside
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
nat-control
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dns
nat (outside) 0 access-list outside_nat0_outbound outside
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.200.200.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA mode transport
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 1.1.1.1 
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map 2 match address outside_2_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 2 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 2 set peer 2.2.2.2
crypto map outside_map 2 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map 3 match address outside_3_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 3 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 3 set peer 3.3.3.3
crypto map outside_map 3 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 5
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 30
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
ssh timeout 15
ssh version 2
console timeout 0
dhcpd auto_config outside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics port
threat-detection statistics protocol
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
 enable inside
 enable outside
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-win-2.4.1012-k9.pkg 1
group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
 dns-server value 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
 vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec l2tp-ipsec 
 ip-comp disable
 pfs disable
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec l2tp-ipsec svc webvpn
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl
 webvpn
  svc ask enable
username user1 password ***** nt-encrypted privilege 15
username user1 attributes
 vpn-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
username user2 password ***** nt-encrypted
username user2 attributes
 vpn-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
 service-type remote-access
username user3 password ***** encrypted
username user3 attributes
 vpn-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
 service-type remote-access
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 address-pool RA-pool
 default-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
 strip-realm
 strip-group
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
 isakmp keepalive disable
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 authentication ms-chap-v2
tunnel-group DefaultWEBVPNGroup general-attributes
 address-pool RA-pool
 dhcp-server 10.100.20.254
tunnel-group 1.1.1.1 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 1.1.1.1 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
tunnel-group 2.2.2.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.2.2 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
tunnel-group 3.3.3.3 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 3.3.3.3 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
!
!
prompt hostname context 
Cryptochecksum:e78f2c61bd1c3b5dea31af3782a04b51
: end
```

Comment: Sounds like the addresses in the vpnclientpool either don't have a route to the remote site, or are being blocked by an ACL.  Hard to say which without seeing your config.  Posting it would help.

Comment: my thinking exactly, but where?  I added the config above.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0
```

combined with this:

```
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl
```

is allowing only traffic on 10.100.20.0 onto the splitTunnel. So a VPN client tries to connect to one of your other private IPs, and actually gets routed outside the tunnel, to the Internet.  Not what you want.

Add your other private IPs to the tunnel with:

```
 access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit X.X.X.X Y.Y.Y.Y
```

for all of your other private IPs.

Comment: ok, I added the changes, but it still doesn't work.  Interestingly, using the "test-pool" DHCP range which overlaps the internal network allows me to get to all the other sites, but not the site I'm VPN'ed to (10.100.20.0/24).

Comment: Try adding the private IPs to the outside_nat0_outbound ACL.

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that doesn't seem to help either.  Is there a way I can trace this to see where the fault may be?

Comment: also, do I need to clear any connections to realize these changes, just in case I'm falsely assuming it's not working based on ping alone.

Comment: Yes, after updating the splitTunnel you'll need to drop & reconnect the VPN client.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.  I've even compared my config to the example given at http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a008046f307.shtml

Comment: Try firing up the ADSM GUI interface, and using the packet tracer.  It ain't perfect, but it might catch an error in an access-list.

Comment: I use that often, however my results are inconclusive.  Many times the packet tracer shows the packet allowed, however, from my perspective it just doesn't work.  I do most of the work in ADSM which results in rather messy CLI code unfortunately.  I'm still open to any other ideas, though.  I'm considering installing OpenVPN internally for remote user access and leave the ASA for site-to-site only if I can't get this to work soon.

Comment: FWIW, OpenVPN was the working solution I ended up using.  The ASA still handles all site-to-site VPNs and Client VPNs connect to the OpenVPN access server on the internal network via port forwarding.  Once on the internal network, standard NAT/routing handles the inter-site traffic.

Answer (score 0):

same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

to hairpin in the central site, then back out the same interface to reach the spoke sites